# pdfkit - doesn't fill "Button" type programmatically

Tags: javascript, node.js, pdf-generation, node-pdfkit

I am trying to fill checkbox programmatically in PDF form, using `node-pdftk` and `pdftk`. I have dumbed the field names and it's state options trying to fill it but no luck

```sh
$ pdftk some_pdf.pdf dump_data_fields_utf8
---
FieldType: Button
FieldName: Zaškrtávací pole 01
FieldFlags: 0
FieldJustification: Left
FieldStateOption: Ano0
FieldStateOption: Ano1
FieldStateOption: Ano2
FieldStateOption: Ano3
FieldStateOption: Ano4
FieldStateOption: Ano5
FieldStateOption: Ano6
FieldStateOption: Off
```

trying to set it using:

```js
pdftk
            .input(originalPdfPath)
            .fillForm({
               'Zaškrtávací pole 01' : 'Ano0',
               'Textové pole3' : 'Test using UTF8 field name',
             })
            .output()
            .then(buffer => {

                return buffer;
            }).catch((e) => {
                console.error(e)
            })
```

The textfield `'Textové pole3'` gets filled, just checkbox doesn't.

Also I tried to rename the `FieldName` to `field1` and set it again but no luck either. 
No error in console or server.

How do I "check" that field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So at the end i made my own lib to work with filling pdf acroforms

https://www.npmjs.com/package/pdftk-fill-pdf

including checkboxes